# QAF | Passing new locator on failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, qaf

During locator failure, I want to pass a newly generated locator on the fly. I'm aware of the QAF's inbuilt multiple locator strategy but in my case locator may change during the run so I will not get new locator info before the run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with qaf 3.0.1 you can set by in `QAFExtendedWebElement`. Best way is to use element listener. For example

```java
@Override
public void onFailure(QAFExtendedWebElement element, CommandTracker commandTracker) {
    //By newBy = <do needful>;
    element.setBy(newBy);
    commandTracker.setRetry(true);
}
```

qaf 3.0.1b is released, you can try that.

EDIT: to handle find element failure you can use driver listener. For example:

```
   private static final Map<String, Object> byToString = JSONUtil.toMap(
            "{'ByCssSelector':'css selector','ByClassName':'class name','ByXPath':'xpath','ByPartialLinkText':'partial link text','ById':'id','ByLinkText':'link text','ByName':'name'}");

    @Override
    public void onFailure(QAFExtendedWebDriver driver, CommandTracker commandTracker) {

        Map<String, Object> parameters = commandTracker.getParameters();
        if (parameters != null && parameters.containsKey("using") && parameters.containsKey("value")) {
            By actaulBy = LocatorUtil.getBy(String.format("%s=%s", parameters.get("using"), parameters.get("value")));
            By newBy = <do the needful>
            commandTracker.getParameters().putAll(toParams(newBy));
            commandTracker.setRetry(true);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> toParams(By by) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String val = by.toString().split(":", 2)[1].trim();
        map.put("using", byToString.get(by.getClass().getSimpleName()).toString());
        map.put("value", val);

        return map;

    }
```

Comment: I got the onFailure function to trigger with QAF 3.0.1b, but was not able to pass the new locator for the step.

I tried following:

   By newBy = By.xpath("//*[@id='txtPassword']");
    element.setBy(newBy);
    commandTracker.setRetry(true);

Also tried another:

@FindBy(locator = "id=txtPassword");
By newBy = LocatorUtil.getBy(locator);
element.setBy(newBy);
commandTracker.setRetry(true);

Comment: Can I update the existing locator using getBundle().setProperty("loc.id.2", "['id=txtPassword']"); and trigger commandTracker.setRetry(true);   ?

Comment: refer updated answer. Find element failure will not trigger element onFailure listener, it can be handled through driver onFailure.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and extended help. Since I'm new to Java, can you please help me how to pass a new locator to By newBy = <do the needful>. Eg: my old locator is "xpath=//loc" but new loc is "xpath=//locnew".

Note: When my locator was failing webelement listener was getting triggered, but I was not able to pass the new locator.

Comment: `LocatorUtil.getBy("xpath=//locnew")` or `By.xpath("//locnew")`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it worked...    LocatorUtil.getBy("xpath://locnew")

Comment: Any reason why the test is starting from the start again not continuing from the element it has failed?

Comment: the best way to find the reason is running in debug mode. you can run testng test/suite in debug mode.